# Why is Windows showing less volume for an external monitor's speakers?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, audio, external-display, speakers

When a friend's laptop was connected to an external HDMI monitor with integrated speakers, the volume attainable through the laptop speakers was louder than that attainable through the external monitor.

Hardware differences could easily account for the volume differences.

But what was odd was the Windows 7 sound control panel.  The image below is an example of that control panel (but on their system, *Headphones* would be replaced by the external monitor's speakers).

[image: Windows 7 Sound control panel]

Even though all volumes were turned up to 100%, when the laptop's speakers were set as the default, the green level indicators would fill all the bars (during loud sounds), but when the external monitor's speakers were set as the default, the green level indicators would never fill more than half the bars.

Why is this, and can anything be done to improve the volume on the external monitor?

Comment: Does your external monitor have a built-in menu where you can change sound?

Comment: @Bungicasse Excellent question.  Yes.  At first it was only turned to 70%, but even when it was adjusted to 100%, the green level indicators in the *Sound* control panel never exceeded 50%.  Yet for the laptop speakers, they reached 100%.